# find xib for iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xib

I load my xib files through: `initWithNibName` programatically. If I set something like: `[[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];`

Shouldn't it load `LoginController.xib` if it is executed on iPhone and search for `LoginController-iPad.xib` on the iPad? This is not happening at my code, do I have to select the right one manually or is something going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe `LoginController~ipad.xib`... tilde + lowercase. you will find more information about these thing in the naming conventions section of the Apple Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, so perhaps this naming convention did not exist when [@shaggy frog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161161/shaggy-frog) answered this question, but iOS should indeed load the iPad specific xib if it is named correctly. In this case your naming is slightly off, the correct naming scheme for an iPad specific xib is

```
NameOfYourViewController~ipad.xib
```

Note that it's a tilde (**~**) instead of a dash (**-**) and ipad is in lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing in the documentation that suggests "`-iPad`" is a valid resource-like modifier for `initWithNibName:`, or that `initWithNibName:` supports modifiers at all.

BTW, `.xib` files are compiled to `.nib` files by Xcode, so the application never sees a `.xib`.